# How can i use different listviews in fragments with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, tabs, android-viewpager

I am using PagerSlidingTabs. I have two fragment and each fragment has one listview. I added TabListener, because i want to go first item in listview when user reselect the same tab. This is working only on the second fragment(tab). Problem is second listview's `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` method working but first listview's `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` method(all methods) not working. First listview is showing properly on screen but it's id seems to second listview's id.

PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private int mPageCount;

public PagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, int pageCount) {
    super(fm);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mPageCount = pageCount;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mPageCount;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return Fragment1.newInstance(position);
        case 1:
            return Fragment2.newInstance(position);

        default:
            return null;
    }

}}
```

Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
private ListView mListView1;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;

public static Fragment1 newInstance(int position) {
    Fragment1 f = new Fragment1();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mRootView == null) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        mListView1 = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        .
        .
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), mListView1, R.layout.list_item, mDatas);
            mListView1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        .
        .
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).getPagerSlidingTabStrip().setOnTabListener(new TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(View tab, int postion) {
                mListView1.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                //mListView1's id seems to mListView2's id
                //when reselect first tab, application acting like i reselect second tab.
            }
        });
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup) mRootView.getParent()).removeView(mRootView);
    }
    return mRootView;
}}
```

Fragment2:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
private ListView mListView2;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;

public static Fragment2 newInstance(int position) {
    Fragment2 f = new Fragment2();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mRootView == null) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        mListView2 = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        .
        .
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), mListView2, R.layout.list_item, mDatas);
            mListView2.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        .
        .
        ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).getPagerSlidingTabStrip().setOnTabListener(new TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(View tab, int postion) {
                mListView2.smoothScrollToPosition(0); //this line is working fine
            }
        });
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup) mRootView.getParent()).removeView(mRootView);
    }
    return mRootView;
}}
```

Fragment1 and Fragment2 have only listview(id:listview1, id:listview2).
HomeActivity have PagerSlidingTabs view and viewpager.

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the listener from the second fragment, that replaces the listener from the first. That's why all the calls seem to be going to the second tab: its listener was the last one added, so it's receiving all the callbacks. One potential solution is to declare an interface, let's call it OnTabReselctedListener, that has a method `onTabReselected(into position)`. Have your activity maintain a list of those interfaces, have your fragments implement that interface, and register those fragments as listeners in the activity. When the activity receives a reselection event, it can pass that to its children fragments; those fragments check if the position matches their own position and scroll to the top if they do. I hope that made sense; I'm writing this from my phone so I can't easily wrote sample code. If you want me to write some, let me know!

Comment: I understand the problem now. I fixed it and it is working fine now. Thank you @nathan:)